Do I ethically need to acknowledge a collegue's confidential work if I consider it obvious?
A colleague of mine that I worked with a number of years ago completed some work that he formally presented and discussed with me in a confidential setting. The work involved a new product design (this is in engineering research) that he had published on at that time (let's call this Product A). Product A is an advance over the well-known industry standard Product P.
He then took this a step further by taking his new Product A and combining it with another standard product (let's call this Product N), the combination of which could be used in a known application (let's call this Application G). He admittedly was the first to propose Product A and Product N for Application G. However, I consider it exceptionally well-known and obvious that Product P can be combined with Product N for use in Application G; this is discussed frequently in my field and there are many papers on this topic that I can cite. While he discussed combining Product A and Product N for Application G, he never bothered publishing this idea.
I worked independently to produce even better designs of the products, let's call these Av2 and Nv2. I designed these for use with Application G. Av2 and Nv2 bear passing similarity to A and N (since they serve the same purposes), but I consider this similarity irrelevant since my products are clearly superior.
I published a paper detailing Av2 and Nv2 combined for use in Application G. To my surprise, my former colleague emailed me wanting to know why I hadn't acknowledged his contributions - since he confidentially showed me his A and N for use in Application G and then never published it. I told him the obvious: everyone knows about combining P and N for application G; he had already published A as an advancement of P, so clearly, the combination of A and N for application G was in no way novel. Since my Av2 and Nv2 were objectively superior to his work, there is certainly no requirement that I would need to acknowledge his so-called "contributions".
He doesn't seem to accept my explanation, and keeps on trying to argue about ethics. Are there any sources that I can use to help him understand that I obviously have no need to acknowledge his conversations? Or perhaps some reference that will show that if the combination of Product P and Product N for use in Application G is well-known, that I am free to publish on product Av2 and Nv2 combined for Application G without needing to acknowledge the combination of A and N?
Thank you!

Did you cite the paper in which they "published A as an advancement of P"? Why did you publish "a paper detailing Av2 and Nv2 combined for use in Application G" when you consider "the combination of A and N for application G was in no way novel" and Av2 and Nv2 as just another step from A, P and N?

This line of argument does not make much sense: "I consider this similarity irrelevant since my products are clearly superior." "Since my Av2 and Nv2 were objectively superior to his work, there is certainly no requirement that I would need to acknowledge his so-called "contributions"." Whether you should acknowledge previous work has nothing to do with whether your work is "superior".

@MisterMiyagi yes, I did cite the paper in which my colleague "published A as an advancement of P". To clarify, Av2 and Nv2 are a huge step from A, P and N; i.e., I have increased their performance by a large margin.

What would you lose by acknowledging him?

@deee 6 Yes, exactly. It never hurts to cite or acknowledge others.

You are looking for objective criteria when you need to acknowledge someone's contributions, but you are missing a critical piece: You are dealing with people who have feelings, opinions, careers to build, reports to write in which they describe what they have accomplished, and so on. People are not always objective or rational, and in a sense that's what makes life wonderful too!
I'm a big believer in being generous in praise. If your colleague showed you their designs, it is not unreasonable for them to believe (and in fact, for others to think so too) that that might have at least inspired your designs. It does not take away anything from your accomplishment to acknowledge this inspiration in your paper, via a reference, or a statement in the acknowledgments of the paper. But it buys you good will and just good karma that you might need at other points in your career -- it's always good to have friends.
In other words, there are little things you can do in being nice to others and showing appreciation that cost you very little but may have a substantial positive impact on you in the future. Be that person who is generous, caring, and who people like working with; rather than one who is a stickler for rules and rigorous in delineating who exactly needs to and need not be acknowledged.

This doesn't exactly answer the question, but I will entertain the notion. If this were a broadly accepted proposition, wouldn't it be found in a code of ethics somewhere?

Codes of ethics describe how people are required to behave. What I'm describing is how people should behave given that we are all working with people, in collaborative environments in which human aspects matter just as much as technical ones.
